# How I can scale object in the upward direction in this case in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I want to make a cube scaling by my mouse drag. However, the cube would be scaling in the up and down direction, I only want to scale in the up direction.
Here is my code, could someone please help me?

```
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    InitialScale = transform.localScale;
    InitialPos = transform.localPosition;
    mainCamera = Camera.main;
    CameraZDistance = mainCamera.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position).z;
}

void Update()
{
    onMouseDrag();
}

private void onMouseDrag()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) { 
        Vector3 MouseScreenPosition = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, CameraZDistance);
        Vector3 mouseWorldPosition = mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(MouseScreenPosition); // Screen point convert to world point
       
        //change transform
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(InitialPos, mouseWorldPosition);
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(InitialScale.x, distance / 2f, InitialScale.z);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could probably adjust its position based on the scale factor too. For example: Y-scale 1, Y 0; Y-scale 2, Y 1.5, Y-scale 3, Y 2; Y-scale 0.5, Y -0.25. There may be a proper Unity way though (I don't do Unity dev).

Answer (score 0):

By default, when you create a gameobject (cube in this case), it's pivot is the center of the cube. So when you scale it in the y direction, it scales up and down equally. To scale only upwards, you want to put the pivot at the bottom of the cube, at position (0.5, 0, 0.5). To change the pivot position, you can do it in the transform section of the inspector panel in the unity editor. Alternative you can also do it through scripting by similarly referencing the transform of that cube.

Edit:
@Llama solution would work (moving the cube upwards as you scale it). I've used this solution before and if I recall correctly, there were no performance issues, however using the pivots would be the proper way to do it and I would assume it would perform better and more smoothly.